# Woocommerce checkout only refresh on postcode

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to make checkout faster and my shipping is only based on the postcode so I do not want 'order review' to refresh when address, country, state is change.

I know I need to fiddle with: woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php

Specifically: update_order_review();

Is there a way to do this by adding code to my themes functions.php rather than comment out core code?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so that there is a legal way of doing it. But there is a work around to it. You can remove woocommerce default fields from your checkout form and add your custom fields. - This way it will not trigger ajax on its update.

You can add/remove custom fields on checkout this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'vid_remove_billing_postcode_checkout' );

function vid_remove_billing_postcode_checkout( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );
  return $fields;
}
```